# dynamically created UIB popover with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have:

```
`$scope['dynamicPopover'+index] = "dd";`
```

How can I bind it in my html page select element(uib-popover). I have tried the below code:

```
<select class="trim-select" ng-model="trim"  uib-popover="{{'dynamicPopover'+$index}}"  popover-trigger="mouseenter"name="trim{{$index}}" id="trim{{$index}}" ng-change="changeDetails($index, trim)" style="display:none !important;"></select>
```

I want to get `{{'dynamicPopover'+$index}}` as dynamicPopover0, then only I can get the value of `dd` in my view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `uib-popover="{{'dynamicPopover'+$index}}"` to `{{dynamicPopover + $index}}` ?
Also, you need to share a bit more of your code for a full understanding. I can probably guess it's a ng-repeat though.

Comment: I tried that as well.. But no result. All the select box are creating dynamically on button click through ng- repeat